# Trying to bottom-center an item in a column, but it keeps left-aligning

Tags: flutter, footer, centering

I'm trying to bottom-center a widget at the bottom of a `Column`, but it keeps aligning to the left.

```
return new Column(
  new Stack(
    new Positioned(
      bottom: 0.0, 
      new Center(
        new Container(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

The existence of the `Positioned` forces the `Container` to the left, instead of centering. Removing the `Positioned`, however, puts the `Container` in the middle-center.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

[Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) is the way to go if you have only one `child`.

If you have more, consider doing something like this:

```
return new Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
  children: <Widget>[
      // Your elements here
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 130):

The easiest and the correct way to do it - use Spacer()

Example:

```
Column(
    children: [
      SomeWidgetOnTheTop(),
      Spacer(),
      SomeCenterredBottomWidget(),
    ],
);
```

Comment: not working if column in SingleChildScrollView

Comment: @evals How to use Spacer()  in the case of parent being SingleChildScrollView() ?

Comment: Nice. Spacer() is equals to Expanded(child: Container())

Comment: Spacer doesn't work if you want other widgets of the column to be in the center and just one at the bottom

Comment: @who-aditya-nawandar No, it works. I use `.center` for both of `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment` parameter inside the `Column` widget. The children which has to be in the center, i wrap it using `Center`. And i use `Spacer` between of the `Center`. So the order inside `Column` is: `Spacer`, `Center`, `Spacer`, `YourWidget`

Answer (score 77):

```
Expanded(
  child: Align(
    alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
          child: //Your widget here,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: @Eliaber Lopes Ta ;-)

Comment: @Prasath Good to hear buddy!

Answer (score 44):

I have used this approach,

What i want is, A `layout` always in bottom but whenever Keyboard pops-up that `layout` also comes over it

[image]

```
body: Container(
        color: Colors.amber,
        height: double.maxFinite,
        child: new Stack(
          //alignment:new Alignment(x, y)
          children: <Widget>[
            new Positioned(
              child: myWidget(context, data.iconName, Colors.red),
            ),
            new Positioned(
              child: new Align(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                child: myWidget(context, data.iconName, Colors.green)
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 27):

1) You can use an [Align](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget, with `FractionalOffset.bottomCenter`.

2) You can also set `left: 0.0` and `right: 0.0` in the `Positioned`.

Answer (score 14):

Just expanding the answers:

- [`Spacer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html) is an option no one mentioned yet; it is used in case you prefer not to use `Positioned` / `Align`.
- [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) works if you want to specify the alignment of a child inside a parent. Use it anywhere but directly inside `Stack`
- [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) is similar to Align, but works only under `Stack` directly.

Comment: Spacer ... dead simple solution. Thx. My tree is: Scaffold > Container > Column > [ItemAtTop, Spacer, ItemAtBottom]. Now ItemAtTop is at top, ItemAtBottom is always at bottom.

Answer (score 13):

Design everything using `Expanded()` is one of the easiest way to do this[image]

```
Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Placeholder(),
                flex: 1,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child:  Placeholder(),
                flex: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Placeholder(),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 10):

If you wish to leave content as it, can wrap it with scrollable.

Useful if you have inputs in the children:

[image]

```
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                  children: children
                    ..add(Container(
                      height: 56, // button heigh, so could scroll underlapping area
                    )))),
        ),
        Positioned(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: button,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

```
Widget _bottom() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: new List<int>.generate(50, (index) => index + 1)
                    .map((item) {
                  return Text(
                    item.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'BoTToM',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 33),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your Container in SingleChildScrollView() widget. Then it will not come above when keyboard pops up.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of Stack:
to avoid floating container on keyboard, use this

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: getAppBar(title),
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body:
```