# Building Layouts Flutter - Columns and Container

Tags: flutter, layout, containers

God day,

I'm having a trouble with layouts in flutter, anyone can help?

**EDIT:**

i will try to explain better.

I have this screen:

[image]

With this code:

```
return new Container(
      height: height,
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: new Card(
          elevation: 10.0,
          child:
          new Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
                new ListTile(
                  trailing:
                  _buildCounterButton(),
                  title: new Center(child: new Text('VENDAS POR PRODUTOS', style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  subtitle: new Center(child: new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0), child:
                  new Text('Top 3 produtos dos últimos 30 dias', textAlign: TextAlign.center,))),
                ),


                        new FutureBuilder<List<RelatorioProdutos>>(
                          future: fetchRelatorioPorProduto(new http.Client(),'$dateInicial', '$dateFinal'),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                            else
                              auxTelaDetalhada = RelatorioVendasTotalizadasProdutos(prods: snapshot.data, aondeVoltar: 0,);

                            return snapshot.hasData
                                ? new porProdutoList(listas: snapshot.data)
                                : new Center(child: new RefreshProgressIndicator());

                          },
                        ),

                new Expanded(
                    child: new Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                        child: new RaisedButton(
                            child: new Text("Relatório Completo",
                              style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            elevation: 8.0,
                            splashColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                context,
                                new MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => auxTelaDetalhada),
                              );
                            }
                        ),))),
            ],)        
      ),
    );
```

I want to have this screen in the end of process.

But i have this method:

```
new FutureBuilder<List<RelatorioProdutos>>(
                          future: fetchRelatorioPorProduto(new http.Client(),'$dateInicial', '$dateFinal'),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                            else
                              auxTelaDetalhada = RelatorioVendasTotalizadasProdutos(prods: snapshot.data, aondeVoltar: 0,);

                            return snapshot.hasData
                                ? new porProdutoList(listas: snapshot.data)
                                : new Center(child: new RefreshProgressIndicator());

                          },
                        ),
```

And this method loads a json request, and i need the button to appear only at the end of json request.

So i was trying to put this RaisedButton in the other method return, with this the button appear only on the end of json request. But, i can't align this button when i put it inside the other method.

Other method:

```
Widget test =

        new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            listaTiles[0],
            listaTiles[1],
            listaTiles[2]]);



      return test;
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
 Widget test =

      new Column(children: <Widget>[
        new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              listaTiles[0],
              listaTiles[1],
              listaTiles[2]]),
        new Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                      child: new Text("Relatório Completo",
                        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      elevation: 8.0,
                      splashColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(
                          context,
                          new MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => auxTelaDetalhada),
                        );
                      }
                  ),)),
      ],);
```

But I get this:

[image]

Anyone have any idea to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...
This question is answered here [Flutter: Trying to bottom-center an item in a Column, but it keeps left-aligning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746636/flutter-trying-to-bottom-center-an-item-in-a-column-but-it-keeps-left-aligning)

```
return new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
          //your elements here
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I should write it in the comments but it requires **50 reputation** but anyways..

This will help you and if you want to center it then wrap the column in the center widget

```
Center(
            child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Container(Text("Hello to all", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 60.0)))
                    ],
                  ),
          ),
```

This would produce following result. Hope this is what you are looking for:)
[image]