# How to align the child of a column on the bottom while keeping other children's position at the center in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to align the text "2022" on the bottom of the screen while keeping the image and its neighbor text at the center of the screen.

[image]

```
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Globalcolors.mainColor,
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/images/splash_logo.png',
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
              child: Text(
                'Sample Text',
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 36,
                    fontFamily: 'MouseMemoirs'),
              ),
            ),
            const Text(
              '2022',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45746636/flutter-trying-to-bottom-center-an-item-in-a-column-but-it-keeps-left-aligning) to solve the problem. I used `Expanded`:

```
const Expanded(
              child: Align(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                child: Text(
                  '2022',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                ),
              ),
            )
```

But, The result is not good:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user Stack and column widgets like

```
Stack(
    children: [
        Column(), // contains the image and title
        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Text("2022"),
        ),
    ]
)
```

You can also use `Positioned` widget to align the text `2022`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the bottom method that comes with the scaffold

```
Scaffold(
 bottom : Text("2020")
)
```

this will make the text always on the bottom of the screen